# Show correct URL for Google Analytics subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I've set up a new Google Analytics account for a client who has a www. main domain and a shop. subdomain. GA is tracking all the interior pages of both domain and subdomain correctly. However, the one issue is that it tracks the two home pages the same, showing just the site root forward, /. I'm seeing this on the real-time overview and in the content section (although that does show page title, so I can differentiate there).

Is there a way to get GA to show a more specific URL instead of just / for primary domain and subdomains?

Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a filter that includes the hostname. To do this:

1) Create a new filter

2) Filter type: Custom filter > Advanced

3) Field A -> Extract A:     Hostname (.*)
   Field B -> Extract B:     Request URI (.*)
   Output To -> Constructor: Request URI $A1$B1

Field A Required: Yes
   Field B Requered: No
   Override Output Field: Yes
   Case Sensitive: No

NOTE: Once you enable this filter, your pages starting that day forward will include the both the hostname and request URI i.e. it's not retroactive.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Just so I understand a bit better as to what's going on, can you clarify what $A1$B1 string is about?

Comment: There is some documentation on the constructor on [Google Analytics support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en), but basically, it's constructing the hostname ($A1) with the Request URI ($B1) to create a new Request URI ($A1$B1).